# Два параметра в лямбда-выражении

Tags: java

Как лямбда-выражению передать два разных параметра?
Например

```
Function<Integer, String> getConcatenatedString = (amount, s) -> {...}
```

amount - Integer, s - String.

Есть ли еще какая-то возможность, кроме как определения интерфейса вроде:

```
 @FunctionalInterface
 interface Function3<A, B, R> {
    public R apply (A a, B b);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, Вам нужна следующая конструкция:

```
BiFunction<Integer, String, String> getConcatenatedString =
    (Integer amount, String s) -> { 
        return Integer.toString(amount) + " " + s;
    };
```

Кстати, поскольку выражение в лямбде единственно, её можно записать покороче:

```
BiFunction<Integer, String, String> getConcatenatedString =
    (Integer amount, String s) -> Integer.toString(amount) + " " + s;
```

Comment: Спасибо :) Уже нашел )))))))))))

Answer (score 3):

Сам же и отвечу на свой вопрос. С помощью BiFunction....

```
BiFunction<Integer, String, String> getConcatenatedString = (amount, s) ->{...}
```